# What is the default timeout value for curl?

Tags: command-line, curl

What is the default value of the `curl` command's timeout? If it's the default socket timeout, then how do I get that value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by @scai at [this Unix and Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94612/70524) is still correct. From [`lib/connect.h`](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/connect.h):

```
#define DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT 300000 /* milliseconds == five minutes */
```